# Access Violation on iOS when use IFMXImageManagerService

Tags: delphi

I'm using this simple code:

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var servicios: IFMXImageManagerService;
    i:integer;
begin
    i:=servicios.GetCount;
    showmessage(inttostr(i));
end;
```

And I get an iOS message with: "Access Violation at address 0000000104BB0460, accessing address 00000000000000000".

All that I try with IFMXImageManagerService fires that violation message.

Please, anyone know why?

Thanks!

Comment: Regardless of Remy's answer, IFMXImageManagerService is not implemented in FMX anywhere anyway, which means the documentation is misleading: http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Sydney/en/FMX.MediaLibrary.IFMXImageManagerService

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not initializing `servicios` to point at anything meaningful, so of course calling any methods on it, like `servicios.GetCount()`, will fail.

You need to use [`TPlatformServices.GetPlatformService()`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/FMX.Platform.TPlatformServices.GetPlatformService) or [`TPlatformServices.SupportsPlatformService()`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/FMX.Platform.TPlatformServices.SupportsPlatformService) to initialize `servicios`.  This is explained in Embarcadero's documentation:

[FireMonkey Platform Services](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/FireMonkey_Platform_Services)

> To use a platform service, you must:
>
> - [Add a reference](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Adding_a_Unit_Reference) to the unit where your service is declared, such as FMX.Platform, to your unit.
> - Call [`TPlatformServices.SupportsPlatformService`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/FMX.Platform.TPlatformServices.SupportsPlatformService) with the target platform service as a parameter to determine whether or not the specified platform service is supported at run time.
> - If `SupportsPlatformService` returns True, use [`TPlatformServices.GetPlatformService`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/FMX.Platform.TPlatformServices.GetPlatformService) to access the actual platform service, and cast the returned service appropriately. You can alternatively use `SupportsPlatformService` to obtain the service as well.

Try this:

```pascal
uses
  ..., FMX.Platform, FMX.MediaLibrary;

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  servicios: IFMXImageManagerService;
  i: integer;
begin
  if TPlatformServices.Current.SupportsPlatformService(IFMXImageManagerService, IInterface(servicios)) then
  begin
    i := servicios.GetCount;
    ShowMessage(IntToStr(i));
  end else
    ShowMessage('Image Manager not supported');
end;
```

Comment: Thank you very much!!, I want to use IFMXImageManagerService for insert and get images from gallery. I'm not sure if I can do it. Only I want that my App insert a image in to gallery (or private images directory or anything that can view in to phone gallery like WhatsApp), and then, get same image for make modifictions and save again, but image must be view in phone gallery. Thanks!!

Comment: IFMXImageManagerService is not supported by iOS :-(, please, know you any alternative to save and get image files from/to gallery?, is not problem if must be any paralell gallery like WhatsApp (that have their own gallery that can view on general gallery phone). Thanks.